# Leaflet map loads incorrectly when inside a Bootstrap .collapse element

Tags: leaflet, bootstrap-framework

I'm trying to create a Leaflet map which is hidden when the page loads, and revealed when the user clicks a button.

I'm trying to use the [Bootstrap collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) functionality to reveal the map on a button press - sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/slead/0nn8wt0o/3/).

This works to show/hide the map's div - but the formatting of the map is broken, with a large empty area with no data:

[image]

This only occurs when the map's div has the `.collapse` class - if you remove that class the map loads correctly.

So the question is, how to allow a Leaflet map to load correctly when it isn't visible when the page loads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412325/resizing-a-leaflet-map-on-container-resize had the answer, which is to call invalidateSize on the map when the collapse event fires:

> Checks if the map container size changed and updates the map if so —
>   call it after you've changed the map size dynamically

```
$('#demo').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    map.invalidateSize(true);
})
```